# Count totals for days within date range

Tags: php, sql, sum

I want to count totals for all mondays, tuesdays, etc. for any given (user selected) date range, StartDate (sDate) through EndDate (eDate). My current query shows all days within range and I'd like it to SUM my table "count" from each day as it is but display total of each day of week as one occurrence. Using image sample, I want my result to be:
Monday - 164
Tuesday - 139
Wednesday - 261
etc.

SQL

```
SELECT areaname,created, SUM(count) as totals FROM reports WHERE created 
between '".$sDate."'  AND  '".$eDate."' AND area = '".$tArea."' GROUP BY areaname, 
created ORDER BY id ASC
```

html

```
foreach ($counts as $row) { ?>
<tr><td><?php echo date('l',strtotime($row['reports']['created'])); ?></td>
<?php echo $row[0]['totals']; ?>
}
```

[image: sum of count for days within date range]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to get the day of the week from a given date, then you can group by that. The syntax is `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W')`. So:

```
SELECT areaname,
  DATE_FORMAT(created, '%W') AS weekday,
  SUM(count) AS totals
FROM reports
WHERE created BETWEEN '".$sDate."' AND '".$eDate."'
  AND area = '".$tArea."'
GROUP BY areaname, weekday
ORDER BY id
```

Note that I left in `areaname` in the GROUP BY, so this will return one result for every combination of `areaname`/`weekday`. If you want totals for all areanames, just remove `areaname` from the GROUP BY clause.